# How can i make embedded raspberry pi OS for Qt application

Tags: linux, qt, raspberry-pi

Is there is any guide to make embedded an OS the only thing it does is launch the software when it boot and doesn't show anything except the application

Comment: I believe the term you are looking for is [*"kiosk"*](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=kiosk+raspberry+pi).

Comment: The answer is vastly different depending on the level of embedding you're interested in. E.g. you can run a Qt application without any window manager loaded ([EGLFS](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html)), or use X11 integration and run it with [XCB](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux.html). In the latter case you could also have the desktop manager load or not, which may also change how you need to configure the startup sequence. Do you have an idea of the direction you want to take?

Comment: For the Qt app itself, with EGLFS it will be shown full-screen automatically, and with X11 with a desktop mananger you may need to call `showFullScreen()` (vs. `show()`) on your top-level `QWidget` (`QMainWindow` or whatever) but that's about it.